# My Postfix server became a spam server. How can I fix this?

Tags: mysql, postfix, mail-server, dovecot

I gotten a VPS recently and I wanted to host my own websites and with that, the ability to send and receive mail.

I set up my mail server according to this guide: https://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

And it worked: I can access the SMTP with STARTTSL and IMAP server with authentication, all on standard port.

But now my Postfix turned into a spam server (currently it has 200+ mails queued up) and I was forced to turn it down. Also it always got all the MySQL connections, and websites couldn't connect to it.

How can I fix my Postfix?

- My main.cf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6480219/
- master.cf : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6480228/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like my server wasn't compromised it just my settings allowed anyone to connect to it, and use it without authentication.

in my `main.cf` I changed the `mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 [::/0]` to `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128` and removed the `permit` from `smtpd_client_restrictions`

after i cleared the queue and started the server none of the problems i experienced seems to appear again.

Answer (score 4):

**Nuke it in orbit!** Your server was compromised, I wouldn't try to "repair it" but plainly starting from 0 and then prevent it gets compromised again.

You can check our network <strike>paranoids</strike> security experts counsels at [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Related:

- [How do you know your server has been compromised?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7443/27973)

Prevent from happening again:

- [Determining the point of compromise on an infected web server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/16305/27973)

Comment: And lock down your postfix server so it doesn't accept mail requests from random mail servers

Comment: by nuke it, you mean the whole server? or just the mail part?